# Generate data label with barcode(html or jpg or pdf) and print it (now barcode does not generate)

Tags: python, html, pdf, printing

Trying to solve a problem linked to bar-codes in html.  What i need to do is to create a template of label with bar-code in it and send to printer. I choosed to use html language to create that template with input data. I could get that html and it looks like this in picture.
[image]
Howerer, then i tried to print that html i got that label but without bar-code printed.  So i tried to convert it to pdf and send to printer, but whenever i tried to convert to pdf, i get in converted pdf that label without bar-codes. 
Tried to use some different libraries (`pdfkit,pdfcrowd,PyQt4.QtGui`), none saved pdf with barcode. Attaching script:

```
for index, row in output_ramco.iterrows():

    print row['PARTNOMLT_OUT']
    htmlas = '''

            <html><head>
            <meta name="author" content="VS">
            <meta name="description" content="include bar code type code39 in html files with javascript">
            <meta name="keywords" content="code39, javascript">
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
            <script language="JavaScript" src="code39.js"></script>
            </head>
                <body style="font-family:Verdana; font-size:11pt">

                <style type="text/css" media = "print">
                        @page 
                {
                    size: auto;   /* auto is the current printer page size */
                    margin: 3mm;  /* this affects the margin in the printer settings */
                }
                .tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
                .tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:8px;padding:5px 4px;border-style:solid;border-width:0px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
                .tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:8px;font-weight:normal;padding:5px 4px;border-style:solid;border-width:0px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
                .tg .tg-9hbo{font-weight:bold;vertical-align:top}
                .tg .tg-yw4l{vertical-align:top}

                </style> 

                <script language="JavaScript">
                document.open();
                Code39("12","175",20,1800,"'''+str(row['PARTNOMLT_OUT'])+'''");
                Code39("12","197",20,1800,"'''+str(row['LOTSN'])+'''");
                document.close();
                </script> 



                <table class="tg" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                  <tr>
                    <td class="tg-9hbo">PN:</td>
                    <td class="tg-yw4l" colspan="2">'''+str(row['PARTNOMLT_OUT'])+'''</td>
                    <td class="tg-9hbo">QTY:</td>
                    <td class="tg-yw4l">'''+str(row['KIEKIS'])+'''</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="tg-yw4l" colspan="5">'''+str(row['PARTDESCMLT_OUT'])+'''</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="tg-9hbo">LOT/SN#:</td>
                    <td class="tg-yw4l" colspan="4">'''+str(row['LOTSN'])+'''</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="tg-9hbo">Stock Status:</td>
                    <td class="tg-yw4l" colspan="4">'''+row['STATUSMLT_OUT']+'''</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="tg-9hbo">Shelf Life Expiry Dt.:</td>
                    <td class="tg-yw4l" colspan="4">'''+row['EXP_DATE']+'''</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="tg-9hbo">Certificate Type/No:</td>
                    <td class="tg-yw4l" colspan="4">'''+str(row['CERTAI'])+'''</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="tg-9hbo">Source Document #</td>
                    <td class="tg-yw4l" colspan="4">'''+str(row['SOURCE_DOC'])+'''</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="tg-9hbo">Storage Area:</td>
                    <td class="tg-yw4l" colspan="4">'''+str(row['STORAGE'])+'''</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="tg-9hbo">Owner # :</td>
                    <td class="tg-yw4l" colspan="4">'''+row['OWNERIS']+'''</td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr>
                    <td class="tg-yw4l" colspan="5">11</td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr>
                    <td class="tg-yw4l" colspan="5">11</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="tg-yw4l">EIA Issue 2</td>
                    <td class="tg-9hbo">Generated On:</td>
                    <td class="tg-yw4l" colspan="3">'''+str(row['GENERATED'])+'''</td>
                  </tr>
                </table>                
                </body>
            </html>

    '''

try:
    with open(dir_files+'html_test.html', 'w') as file:
        file.write(htmlas.encode('UTF-8'))
except Exception, e:
    log_error()


######1st
#from PyQt4.QtGui import QTextDocument, QPrinter, QApplication
#import sys
#app = QApplication(sys.argv)
#doc = QTextDocument()
#location = "html_test.html"
#html = open(location).read()
#doc.setHtml(html)
#printer = QPrinter()
#printer.setOutputFileName("foo.pdf")
#printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter.PdfFormat)
#printer.setPageSize(QPrinter.A4);
#printer.setPageMargins (15,15,15,15,QPrinter.Millimeter);
#doc.print_(printer)


######2nd
#import pdfcrowd
#client = pdfcrowd.Client("orangutangas", "pwd")
#output_file = open('htmlas.pdf', 'wb')
#client.convertHtml(htmlas, output_file)
#output_file.close()


#########3rd
#path_wkthmltopdf = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe'
#config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf=path_wkthmltopdf)
#pdfkit.from_string(htmlas, 'out.pdf',configuration=config)
```

So how can i translate html or make a jpg/pdf where printer can read this info and print properly with barcode thjat label?

Comment: I don't believe the javascript (which looks like it creates the barcode) will be rendered in the file.  For that you need selenium or something else that renders the javascript

Comment: Yes barcode is generated with java script in html. Is there any other possibility how to create that barcode? I know that easily it can be done on excel, but i can't use excel on this project

Comment: I've not used it, but searching for python barcodes turned this up: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyBarcode/0.7  There are lots of other links

Comment: so you think better way is to create barcode with pyBarcode(which saves it as picture) and then attach that picture to html?

Comment: I think it would be easier than figuring out selenium, but I haven't tried either method.  Good luck

Comment: ty, i  will try to do this method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ReportLab is very good in this case. I am not sure where I found out this code. But it really helped me.

```
from reportlab.graphics.barcode import code39, code128, code93
from reportlab.graphics.barcode import eanbc, qr, usps
from reportlab.graphics.shapes import Drawing
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.lib.units import mm
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.graphics import renderPDF

def createBarCodes():
    """
    Create barcode examples and embed in a PDF
    """
    c = canvas.Canvas("barcodes.pdf", pagesize=letter)

    barcode_value = "1234567890"

    barcode39 = code39.Extended39(barcode_value)
    barcode39Std = code39.Standard39(barcode_value, barHeight=20, stop=1)

    # code93 also has an Extended and MultiWidth version
    barcode93 = code93.Standard93(barcode_value)

    barcode128 = code128.Code128(barcode_value)
    # the multiwidth barcode appears to be broken
    #barcode128Multi = code128.MultiWidthBarcode(barcode_value)

    barcode_usps = usps.POSTNET("50158-9999")

    codes = [barcode39, barcode39Std, barcode93, barcode128, barcode_usps]

    x = 1 * mm
    y = 285 * mm
    x1 = 6.4 * mm

    for code in codes:
        code.drawOn(c, x, y)
        y = y - 15 * mm

    # draw the eanbc8 code
    barcode_eanbc8 = eanbc.Ean8BarcodeWidget(barcode_value)
    bounds = barcode_eanbc8.getBounds()
    width = bounds[2] - bounds[0]
    height = bounds[3] - bounds[1]
    d = Drawing(50, 10)
    d.add(barcode_eanbc8)
    renderPDF.draw(d, c, 15, 555)

    # draw the eanbc13 code
    barcode_eanbc13 = eanbc.Ean13BarcodeWidget(barcode_value)
    bounds = barcode_eanbc13.getBounds()
    width = bounds[2] - bounds[0]
    height = bounds[3] - bounds[1]
    d = Drawing(50, 10)
    d.add(barcode_eanbc13)
    renderPDF.draw(d, c, 15, 465)

    # draw a QR code
    qr_code = qr.QrCodeWidget('www.mousevspython.com')
    bounds = qr_code.getBounds()
    width = bounds[2] - bounds[0]
    height = bounds[3] - bounds[1]
    d = Drawing(45, 45, transform=[45./width,0,0,45./height,0,0])
    d.add(qr_code)
    renderPDF.draw(d, c, 15, 405)

    c.save()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    createBarCodes()
```

Comment: Ty sir, i will mark it as answer. I kept my html generation and used PRINTHTML application which i launched from my python script.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this project](https://github.com/libretees/itemize), which uses `jinja2`, `z3c.rml`, and `reportlab` to generate PDFs with barcodes on them. All of these libraries can accomplish what you're trying to do, and you can send labels to the printer with `pycups`.

Comment: thank you veyr much. i have came up with different approach,not to generate pdf and print it, but print html directly to printer